# asynchoronous file upload not working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have a function called make progress which is called by a button Upload. The function is below:

```
<button type="button" id = "Upload" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default" disabled>Upload</button>


function makeProgress(){            
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
      console.log("form data " + formData);
      $.ajax({
          url : '/fileUpload',
          data : formData,
          processData : false,
          contentType : false,
          type : 'POST',
          success : function(data) {
              alert(data);
          },
          error : function(err) {
              alert(err);
          }
     });

        }
```

Controller.java file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Integer uploadFile(
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    try {

        logger.info("file uploaded");

        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

When running it locally i get error 404 on file upload

Comment: 404 means the resource not found, try to hit the targeted url on browser

Comment: Make sure you are hitting the right target, as it can not be found (404 is a HTTP response code for *not found*)

Comment: I am now getting a error 405 - method not found

Comment: Fixed - location was incorrect. Thanks